# Pull-back of the metric tensor via the flow (one parameter group)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, vector-fields

Suppose now that $(, )$ is a Riemannian manifold. Let $\theta_t$ be a (local)
one-parameter group of isometries of $(M, g)$ generating a vector field $X$.
Then
$$(\theta_t)^* = g$$

I wanna make sure I understand this correct.

So by the definition $$(\theta_t)^*g(X,Y)=g((\theta_t)_*X,(\theta_t)_*Y)=g(X(f\circ\theta_t),Y(f\circ\theta_t))$$

but I don't see how $g(X(f\circ\theta_t),Y(f\circ\theta_t))=g(X,Y)$.

Could someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: What is $f$? The equality $((\theta_t)^*g)(X,Y) = g((\theta_t)_*X,(\theta_t)_*Y)$ is the definition of $(\theta_t)^*g$, and so the equality $(\theta_t)^*g=g$ reads $ g((\theta_t)_*X,(\theta_t)_*Y) = g(X,Y)$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Why is the last equality on your comment true ? is my question. And $f$ is just a smooth function to make sense of $((\theta_t)_*X)f=X(f\circ\theta_t)$

Comment: The part involving $f$ is nonsense which is the source of your confusion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan makes sense, thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to get at: if you let a vector field act on a function $f$ as a derivation, the output is again a function, and it does not make sense to feed that to $g$.

Comment: @IvoTerek so to be clear, it's true that $(\theta_t)_*X=X$ on the domain of $\theta$ because it's a one-parameter group of isometries ?

Comment: Yes, because every vector field is related to itself under its own flow. This does not have anything to do with isometries. I'm imagining your next question would be whether $(\theta_t)_*Y=Y$, but you're forgetting that $(\theta_t)^*g =g$ is an **assumption** here.

Comment: @IvoTerek In my notes in doesn't state it as an assumption rather than an observation. I don't know if my notes have a mistake, but that's the reason I was confused. But now raised the question of why a vector field generated by a one-parameter group of isometries is necessarily a Killing vector field.

Comment: It is the definition of a Killing field. Unless you're defining a Killing field to be one with $\mathcal{L}_Xg=0$. Then it's better to review Lie derivatives: it's a general fact that the flow of a vector field preserves any object if and only if the corresponding Lie derivative is zero.

Comment: I think the identity applies to any vector fields, not just the $X$ defined as being generated by $\theta_t$. That is, we have $\theta_t^*g(V, W) = g(V, W)$ for any vector fields $V, W$ on $M$. The step $g((\theta_t)_*V, (\theta_t)_*W) = g(V, W)$ is just the fact that $\theta_t$ is an isometry.